# How to programmatically grant the “Display pop-up windows while running in the background” permission in android?

Tags: android

By default the  **“Display pop-up windows while running in the background”** is disabled, but I've seen some apps which have this permission enabled by default. How to enable this by default in app?

Comment: im facing same problem. Did you have any solution?

Comment: Those apps are whitelisted by Xiaomi to have these permissions granted by default, you need to programmatically open the Other Permission settings page and ask the user to grante the permission